# How to use HttpClient and System.Net.Http.dll in .NET 4.0 project?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, base-class-library

I have used HttpClient in my solution. 
The solution is targeted to .NET 4.0 because of WinXP-Customers, where installing .NET 4.5 is not possible.
After i checked in my changes, TFS has reported that System.Net.dll is not found. 
I found out what problem is - the dll is for .NET 4.5 only. Otherwise you should use Nuget package for HttpClient. The latter has Dependency on Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. Im failed to install it with my NuGet package manager (last version 2.6):

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.8'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Bcl.Build from Microsoft, the license agreement to which 
is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=296407. 
Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own 
license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your 
acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s),
then delete the relevant components from your device:

Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple 
tasks      concurrently.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Net.Http
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What can cause such problems? How i get install the package?

- VS2012 Update 3
- NuGet 2.6.40627.9000
- Solution target: .NET 4.0

**Update**
Have uninstalled some VS extensions, especially:

- [TeamPiligrim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/79e9baa7-ea8b-4335-86ba-ae929bf67222) and
- [TFS Source Control History Visualization](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a8e7330-8395-4915-935f-941dc3bde29c)

closed all TFS-related tool windows,
then restarted VS and it works.

However I would know more about the error message meaning and cause.

Comment: Worked fine for me: http://pastie.org/8250086

Comment: Difficult to say... if it could be explained, it likely would have been detected and fixed already.